# i want to sum a column of sql table where date is current date

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, resultset

i want to sum the values of a column where date is today's date and pass it to a variable. i wrote the following code but it's not working.

> error: "column name sum(Bill_Total) not valid." its considering "sum(Bill_Total)" as a column.

```
String sql = "select sum(Bill_Total) from t_report where date=?";
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setDate(1, date);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
String sum=rs.getString(sql);
```

can someone tell me whats wrong with my query. thanks in advance

Comment: give column name in [Bill_Total] Square brackets and give alias name to the SUM column and try

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql-server? You have tagged with both

Comment: sql server2008.

Comment: can u please show me how to do it @ShakeerMirza

Comment: "select sum([Bill_Total]) as TOTAL_BILL from t_report where date=?" try this.. @MohitJoshi

Comment: `String sum=rs.getString(sql);` definitely won't work. `int sum = rs.getInt(1);` would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(Bill_Total) AS `Bill_Total` 
  FROM t_report 
  WHERE date=?
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it me or the error is when you're fetching the result?

```
String sql = "select sum(Bill_Total) as bill_total from t_report where date=?";
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setDate(1, date);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
String sum=rs.getString("bill_total");
```

Comment: int sum =   rs.getInt("bill_total");

Comment: Can you show the stackTrace? so run the query on the DB to see what's wrong

Comment: use if(rs.next()){ }and then only fetch the data as rs.getString("bill_amount").